# Continuous integration for Xamarin.froms app using Jenkins and fastlane

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration

Is there any ways to run jenkin jobs for `Xamarin.froms` app using Fastlane ?
I searched may but didn't get any proper solutions

Any suggestions thanks in advance?

Comment: Start your research from here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/